# Inserting data into database with WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm new to WordPress development. I need to learn how to use properly the database but I didn't find any tutorial or further explanation on how to do this.

Let's say I have a form with a submit button and I want to create a table (if it's not yet created) and put the values from the form into the table after I press the button. Seems simple but I have no idea on how to do it.

Do I need a php script? If yes, where do I put it? How do I refer the elements of the front-end in this script?

PS: I'm using a theme builder and I didn't have to write a single line of html. That's why I don't know how I would get the reference for the elements of the front-end.

Comment: you need php script to interact with your database, most of the time this goes like a plugin in wordpress that includes php and javascript or any other script needed. Learn to create plugins in wordpress. That would help

Comment: Can you give me an example of a plugin that would do it?

Comment: Not sure if there's a particular plugin for your need, what you're trying to do actually is pretty simple, but just do your research about creating plugins. That would help you learn a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

First give a try WordPress codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

There is a blog post describing how to create mysql tables:
https://samelh.com/blog/2015/08/13/create-mysql-database-table-wordpress-insert-data-wpdb-html-form/